uniqueness of stationary point for strictly convex functions
Good afternoon,
I've read in an article that a strictly convex function has at most one stationary point but I struggle to prove it. I know we can prove for a strictly convex function the uniqueness of the minimum, but is it true for a stationary point?
Thanks in advance.

It would be interesting to see your take! :)

Use the equivalent definition of strict convexity: $f(x)>f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)$, and consider two different stationary points $x,y$.
